# How to apply Control resource on a Control using code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, tabitem

I have created a Control resource for a `TabItem` in the XAML file.  I an generating `TabItem`s dynamically and i want to apply that Control Resource to each and every `TabItem` that gets generated .How to apply that control resource to every other `TabItem` using c# code as soon as they are generated.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. The only thing I understand from this question is that you're not using MVVM and thus you might be creating a horrible mess. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I've done is in my C# Code of the class definition, I hooked into the "Loaded" event.  From that, I try to find the resource of the style and apply if found... something like

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
   public MyTabItem()
   {
      Loaded += MyLoadedExtras;
   }

   private void MyLoadedExtras( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
      object basis = TryFindResource("XKeyValueFromYourTabItemStyle");
      if (basis != null)
         Style = (Style)basis;

      // disconnect from loaded event after our one time in
      Loaded -= MyLoadedExtras;
   }
}
```

So, when you dynamically add an instance of the "MyTabItem", it will immediately look for itself for the resources available and set the style for you.

Comment: Yup... and someone actually down-voted me on it...  As a newbie, be sure to "check" (and up-check) the solutions that helped solve any questions you have posted... its like a thank you, and helps others not bother trying to answer a question that is already solved :)